# Show data from mysql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question about showing data that I load from the database.
I have a table "Deliverables" with "deliverable_image, deliverable_thumbnail" and a FK "item_id". In my items table I have "item_title, item_description, ...".

I can show the images, and if you click on an image I load the Detail action in my controller and send the deliverableid.

Here's what I do:

In my **Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int DeliverableID)
{
    var model = repository.GetDeliverable(DeliverableID);
    return View(model); 
}
```

In my **Repository**:

```
public IEnumerable<items> GetDeliverable(int deliverableid)
{
    return from item in entities.items
           where item.item_id.Equals(deliverableid)
           select item;
}
```

But now, how can I show the details of the deliverables in my view?
I've tried this with no succes:

```
@model IEnumerable<GDMfrontEnd.Models.items>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detail";
}

<h2>Detail</h2>

<fieldset>
{
    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => items.item_description)
    </div>
}

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing down an `IEnumerable<GDMfrontEnd.Models.items>`.  That is your collection you can iterate over.

You can do something like:

```
@foreach(var item in model) {
     <p>
         item.item_id
     </p>
 }
```